# angular-translate - variable and interpolation in the same translation key

Tags: angularjs, angular-translate

Can I have a variable and an interpolation in the same translation key?

Something like this:

```
"notice" : "{{subject}} {RES, select, is{is} are{are} other{are}}",
```

gives me the error on the web browser console:

> Object { message: "Expected [ \t\n\r] or [0-9a-zA-Z$_] but \"{\"
>   found.", expected: (8) […], found: "{", location: {…}, name:
>   "SyntaxError", stack: "" }

When {{subject}} is removed, it works.

Thank you in advance for help.

Comment: @georgeawg I think this is not a duplication. It is a question on angular-translate usage of special custom interpolation for plural translation. In this case, they state that to use variable, it's a different syntax and should use only one curly bracket.
https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/14_pluralization

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are trying to use angular-translate pluralization interpolation message format in combination with normal variable interpolation, it can be done differently. From the [docs](https://angular-translate.github.io/docs/#/guide/14_pluralization):

> The drawback
>
> Actually it's pretty cool that we are able to use MessageFormat as our
>   interpolation engine. Unfortunately, when replacing MessageFormat
>   interpolation with angular-translate's default interpolation, there's
>   a big problem. Take a look at the following code: Do you see any
>   difference?
>
> ```
> {   
>    "DEFAULT_INTERPOLATION": "This is a translation that uses default
>    interpolation with a dynamic value: {{value}}",   
>
>   "MF_INTERPOLATION": "This is a translation that uses MessageFormat
>    interpolation with a dynamic value: {value}" 
> }
> ```
>
> Exactly. MessageFormat uses a different syntax for its interpolation.
>   This means, when using MessageFormat interpolation, you have to rock
>   over all of your translations, check if they use any kind of variable
>   replacement and update them to match the right interpolation syntax.
>   This isn't a cool thing.

Comment: Thank you for help. I've read only the "Variable replacement" part. Good to know, that this topic is covered in "Pluralization".